Can't able to login in Phantom wallet mobile app using Google email
I am not able to login in phamtom wallet app using my google
I have wallet but when i am trying to login it is showing access denied
It is showing (https://auth.phantom.app/login/error?error=access_denied&error_description=The+resource+owner+or+authorization+server+denied+the+request.+The+consent+verifier+has+already+been+used.)
